# Find in a map by value - preference of methods in terms of speed

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

Four methods come to my mind to find in a map by value. What would be the order of preference of the methods in terms of speed?

Assuming both key and value are unique among themselves.

`std::map<int, std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<int, std::string>`

1. Use `boost::bimap` if boost library is available
2. Use `std::find_if` with a predicate/functor with some equality comparison logic
3. At the time of populating `std::map<int, string>`, create & populate 
   another `std::map<std::string, int>` and perform a `map::find` on the second map.
4. Iterate through the whole map and check `if (iter->second == value_to_find)`, 
   if found `break;`

I will be performing find by key at all times and once or twice by value.

Comment: If searching inside your `std::map` by value is a common operation, perhaps you should not be using a `std::map` in the first place.

Comment: I think, 4th method does not make sense when you are using std:map.. why can use map::find instead?

Comment: If want to find by value and key both, boost::bimap is right choice. But if you only want to search by value, why don't you use a map or multimap with the string "value" as the key? Anyway, if you have a problem on the third point, you may have to use a multimap instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options 2 and 4 are doing exactly the same thing: Iterate the whole map entry-by-entry until a matching entry is found. The runtime in both cases is `O(n)`.

The options 1 and 3 are also equivalent. Runtime will be `O(log n)` for a map and `O(1)` for an unordered map. When you pick option 3 you are essentially reinventing the boost:bimap.

So I would recommend you to go for option 1 and use the `boost:bimap` when available. When boost isn't available for whatever reason, you should rebuild the functionality and use two maps and implement the code to keep them synchronized yourself.

This is, of course, all under the premise that you are going to store so many values in this data-structure that it actually matters. When the amount of entries is small, just using a `std::vector` and iterating it manually can actually be the superior solution in regards to speed.

Comment: In my case, map contains a large number of values to make a difference. Vector is not an option.